# XML Schema: usage of minOccurs and maxOccurs within xs:sequence

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Given a valid XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="personinfo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="2">
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

For a valid XML against this XSD, a `<personinfo>` should contain max 2 sequence of `<firstname>` followed by `<lastname>`. I add `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` to `firstname`. For an XML file below:

```
<personinfo>
  <firstname>lalal</firstname>
  <lastname>fwfw</lastname>
  <firstname>lalal</firstname>
  <lastname>fwfw</lastname>
</personinfo>
```

Why is it still valid by [validator](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)? Don't `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` just overwrite the `maxOccurs` by `xs:sequence`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Don't `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` just overwrite the `maxOccurs` by `xs:sequence`?

No, the occurrence constraints on the enclosing `xs:sequence` mean that the group itself, collectively, can together appear or repeat as specified.  The occurrence constraints on the containing individual elements individually affect those elements independent of how the collection of them may occur.

For your XSD, there can be one or two sequences, each with `firstname` (optional) and `lastname` (required).