# Why is minOccurs="0" not allowing an element to be empty?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I've set the element `"FURNITURE"` to `minOccurs="0"` but it still comes back

> Element 'FURNITURE' cannot be empty according to the DTD/Schema.

when I try to validate it

```
<xsd:element name="FURNITURE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="6">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:integer" />
      <xsd:element name="rNumber" type="xsd:string" /> 
      <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

and

```
<FURNITURE />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing `minOccurs="0"` on `FURNITURE`, you're specifying that `FURNITURE` need not be present, but that says nothing about the content model of `FURNITURE`.  In fact, `FURNITURE` must consist of a sequence of `ID`, `rNumber`, and `type` elements which must all be present exactly once.

If you want `FURNITURE` to possibly be empty when present, then make each of those child elements optional individually by adding `minOccurs="0"` to each `xsd:element` or collectively by adding `minOccurs="0"` to the wrapping `xsd:sequence`.

### See also

- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)
- [XML Schema: usage of minOccurs and maxOccurs within xs:sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37974053/290085)