# minOccurs/maxOccurs on xsd:sequence vs xsd:element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, minoccurs

Let say we have the following schema (from a Microsoft sample):

```
<xs:element name="zooAnimals">
  <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <xs:element name="elephant"/>
           <xs:element name="bear"/>
           <xs:element name="giraffe"/>
        </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The sequence is optional, so all elements below can appear or not.

Now, if we have:

```
<xs:element name="zooAnimals">
  <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
           <xs:element name="elephant" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="bear" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
           <xs:element name="giraffe" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Elements `bear` and `giraffe` must be present if `zooAnimals` is present.
Up to now, I'm OK.

But what if we have this (mix of the above example and "real life" XSD)?

```
<xs:element name="zooAnimals">
  <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
           <xs:element name="elephant" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="bear" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
           <xs:element name="giraffe" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

If the sequence is mandatory, why specify `minOccurs` in elements, and why some ones can be with `minOccurs="0"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> elements `bear` and `giraffe` must be present if `zooAnimals` is present.
> Up to now, I'm OK

This may be where you might have to adjust your understanding.

Because the `xs:sequence` is optional, `zooAmimals` may still be present without any of `elephant`, `bear`, or `giraffe` being present.

> If the sequence is mandatory, why specify `minOccurs` in elements, and why some ones can be with `minOccurs="0"`?

You're missing that there are two levels of occurrence constraints in play:

1. On `xs:sequence`, the occurrence constraints apply to the sequence group collectively.  The collective group might be optional, required, or be able to be repeated *as a group*.
2. On the `xs:element` children of `xs:sequence`, the occurrence constraints apply to the children *individually* **after** taking into account the occurrence constraints on the `xs:sequence` as a group.  If the `xs:sequence` is, say, optional, and the group is omitted, the individual `xs:element` constraints do not matter; otherwise, the `xs:element` occurrence constraints govern the occurrences of each element *individually* within each `xs:sequence` group occurrence.

### See also

- [XML Schema minOccurs / maxOccurs default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4821477/290085)
- [Meaning of minOccurs and maxOccurs for xsd:choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28523597/290085)
- [XML Schema: usage of minOccurs and maxOccurs within xs:sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37974053/290085)

Comment: kjhughes: when you say "Because the xs:sequence is optional, zooAmimals may still be present without any...", does it mean that the sequence may be present and empty?

Comment: Close: `xs:sequence/minOccurs="0"` means that that the sequence **as a group** is optional, therefore all of the subordinate elements may be omitted **as a group**, regardless of their individual occurrence constraints.

Comment: Ok, it's clear now. Thank you for your explanations

Answer (score 2):

In your first example

```
   <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xs:element name="elephant"/>
       <xs:element name="bear"/>
       <xs:element name="giraffe"/>
   </xs:sequence>
```

your elements must appear in groups of three: elephant, bear, giraffe, elephant, bear, giraffe, elephant, bear, giraffe, ...

In your second example,

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
   <xs:element name="elephant" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:element name="bear" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
   <xs:element name="giraffe" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

Each group consists of zero elephants, any number of bears, and a giraffe. So you might have E B B B B G E B G B B G. But you can't have E B G G because a G ends the group and the next group must start with E or B.

(This is reminding me of Gödel, Escher, Bach....)

In your third example

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
   <xs:element name="elephant" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:element name="bear" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xs:element name="giraffe" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

The sequence can't repeat. You can have E B G or E or E G or E B, but you can only have one such group, because the sequence itself can only occur once.

Comment: [*smile*]  XSD being XML, the XSD schema schema, XSLT being XML, and XSLT that generates XSLT all remind me fondly of Gödel, Escher, Bach.

Comment: Michaels, your explanations, together with those of KjHughes, make things very clear now. Thank you both